# Zend Frameworks Quickstart find() methods Action and View

Tags: zend-framework, view, action

I am attempting to extend the Zend Framework Quickstart tutorial by trying to make an individual view for each guestbook entry, but I am missing something and keep getting errors like:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\quickstart.local\application\views\scripts\guestbook\display.phtml
```

I get this when trying the following for my displayAction and my display.phtml:

```
//view
<p><?php echo $this->escape($this->entry->id); ?></strong> <a><?php echo $this->escape($this->entry->comment); ?></a><br>
<?php echo $this->escape($this->entry->email); ?></p>

//action
public function displayAction()
{
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');

$entry = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper();
$this->view->entry = $entry->find($id);
}
```

And the find() function in the mapper is as is from the tutorial.

I have look all over the web and have only found tutorials that omit the quickstart guide's structure altogether. While they are all solid in their own right, I would like to find a solution to this. What am I doing wrong?

I am about mid-level with php and a beginner with zend framework. Please keep that in mind when responding.

Comment: The view is assuming that $this->entry is an object when it isn't. The find() method doesn't seem to be returning a result. Have you verified that your database parameters are correct and that $id is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Lee, the database parameters are fine because I am having no issues with the fetchAll() and save() methods.

Comment: First, yes the quickstart guide is relevant and a good start for your needs, second, the `find()` method isn't supposed to take two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're following the quickstart verboten, you'll want something like this

```
public function displayAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = new Application_Model_Guestbook;
    $mapper = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper;

    $mapper->find($id, $model);

    if (null === $model->getId()) {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception(
            sprintf('Guestbook entry %d not found', $id), 404);
    }
    $this->view->entry = $model;
}
```

Comment: Tried this. however I am getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object in..display.phtml. not sure if I am doing that correctly.

Comment: @JremyDeaton Oops, the last line in my answer was using the wrong variable name (changed to `$model`). Try it now

Comment: @phil I'm confused. in your example you are assigning the $model to the view. How is $model returning the data when $mapper is doing the find()? I know these two components work together but this behavior seems counterintuitive. Thanks

Comment: @Phil, I believe I am refrencing it wrong in my display.phtml. This is an example of what I have: `echo $this->escape($this->entry->id)`. However unlike a 'fetchAll' I do not have this contained in a foreach loop.

Comment: Disregard my last comment. Human error. I got it fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

in order to use GuestbookMapper with the Find() method you need to supply two items of information to the method, the id and an instance of Guestbook. The instance of guestbook is required because it has all the getters and setters mapper uses to generate the returned data.

```
//action updated
public function displayAction()
{
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');

$guestbook = new Application_Model_GuestBook();
$entry = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper();
$this->view->entry = $entry->find($id, $guestbook);
}
```

for a detailed explaination of how this works check out chapter 9 of [Survive the Deepend](http://survivethedeepend.com/)